# "ExceptionMessage": "Multiple actions were found that match the request:

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api

Hi found many helpful link to solve this but nothing is working to me :(. Can any one look at this as where I am going wrong?

Controller :

```
[ActionName("savebook")]
        [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage PostSaveBook([FromBody]Book product)
        {
            return Add(product);


        }

        [ActionName("savemobile")]
        [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage PostSaveMobile([FromBody]Mobile product)
        {
            return Add(product);

        }
```

WebApiRouteConfig.

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ControllerOnly",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}"
);

            // Controller with ID
            // To handle routes like `/api/VTRouting/1`
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "ControllerAndId",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: null,
                constraints: new { id = @"^\d+$" } // Only integers 
            );

            // Controllers with Actions
            // To handle routes like `/api/VTRouting/route`
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "ControllerAndAction",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"
            );
```

Error :

**

> "ExceptionMessage": "Multiple actions were found that match the
>   request:

**

Comment: Is the error a run-time or compilation error? If run-time, can you show the url you are using for the request?

Comment: I'm working on my local. so can't :(. However that's very simple steps I guess you can start by creating new project what you say?

Answer (score 0):

The first route that you have registered is the RESTful style route, which doesn't include an `{action}` segment.

As the routes are evaluated in the same order that they are registered, whenever you send a POST request, the controller name will be taken from the URL, and then, the action selector will look for an action whose name starts with `Post`. In your case there are two actions that fulfill this condition: `PostSaveBook` and `PostSaveMobile`.

If the first registered route was the `"ControllerAndAction"` one, the action would be taken from the URL and the action selector could correctly choose the desired action.

If you want to use the RESTful style, you'd have to use [attribute routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) to break the ambiguity.